# I'm unclear about why we use 'to be' in these expressions of preference:

Tags: verbs, subjunctives

In the phrase *'I would rather my computer be on the table'* we see 'to be' being used in a very raw form. Why is that?

In an alternative: *'I would rather it if my laptop were on the table'* we see a conditional form emerge... maybe because of the subject change? Suddenly the verb 'to be' goes into a weird form here (past form of 3rd person singular?). Is that the subjunctive? What's happening here?

Are either of these correct?

Comment: Please proofread your question taking into account you left out the suspect usage of 'to be' . You likely typed in the grammatically correct sentence with out knowing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would rather my computer be on the table

Yep, that's the *subjunctive* mood.  The Wikipedia article has a good explanation:

> The subjunctive mood in English is used to form sentences that express wished-for, tentatively assumed, or hypothetical states of affairs, rather than things that the speaker intends to represent as true and factual. These include statements that express opinion, belief, purpose, intention, or desire.

Some languages like Spanish have a whole separate set of conjugations for subjunctive.  English does something more confusing.  The Wikipedia article continues to explain:

> In Modern English, the subjunctive form of a verb often looks identical to the indicative form, and thus subjunctives are not a very visible grammatical feature of English. For most verbs, the only distinct subjunctive form is found in the third person singular of the present tense, where the subjunctive lacks the -s ending: *It is necessary that he **see** a doctor* (contrasted with the indicative **he sees**). The verb *be*, however, has not only a distinct present subjunctive (*be*, as in *I suggest that he be removed*) but also a past subjunctive were (as in *If he were rich, …*).

The subjunctive is strongly associated with a few specific words and adjectives.  [This site](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm) lists a few of them.  Below is an excerpt:

> Verbs That Attract the Subjunctive Mood
>
> - The following verbs often attract the subjunctive mood: *to ask*, *to command*, *to demand*, *to insist*, *to order*, *to recommend*, *to suggest* and *to wish*.
>
> Adjectives That Attract the Subjunctive Mood
>
> - The following adjectives – especially when used with the word that – often attract the subjunctive mood: *crucial*, *essential*, *important*, *imperative* and *necessary*

The structure *X [modal] rather X be Z* or *X [modal] rather X were Z * is also a common use of subjunctive.  *Prefer* or *wish* could be substituted instead.